# php and regex: how to capture multi-line and stops at first occurrence?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to capture all what is between `<td id="adress">`and `</td>`:

```
<td id="adress">
   hello<br>
   world<br>
   line3<br>
</td>
<td id="adress2">
   hello2<br>
   world2<br>
   line3<br>
</td>
```

That means: multi line capture AND stops at first occurence of 
so result should be:

```
   hello<br>
   world<br>
   line3<br>
```

Any clue ?

I tried with:

```
preg_match_all("/<td id=\"AddressHolder\">.*<\/td>/s", $source, $output_array);
```

But this does not stop at first `</td>`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the regex engine  to stop after the first occurrence then you need to  use `preg_match` function instead of `preg_match_all`.

```
$st = <<<EOT
<td id="adress">
   hello<br>
   world<br>
   line3<br>
</td>
<td id="adress2">
   hello2<br>
   world2<br>
   line3<br>
</td>
EOT;
preg_match('~<td id="adress[^"]*">[^\n]*\n\K.*?(?=\n[^\n]*<\/td>)~s', $st, $match);
print_r($match[0]);
```

**Output:**

```
   hello<br>
   world<br>
   line3<br>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add a question mark after the `.*`, the match will stop at the first occurrence of what follows, e.g. `</td>`.  You don't have to use `preg_match_all` either:

```
$source = <<<EOS
<td id="adress">
   hello<br>
   world<br>
   line3<br>
</td>
<td id="adress2">
   hello2<br>
   world2<br>
   line3<br>
</td>
EOS;

preg_match("/<td id=\"adress\">(.*?)<\/td>/s", $source, $matches);
$address = $matches[1];

print_r($address);
```

Output:

```
hello<br>
world<br>
line3<br>
```